# Use Airflow Bash Operator with Airflow Config values automatically included

Tags: python, bash, airflow

We are using Airflow 2.3.4.

We want to use the Bash Operator to perform Airflow commands.
Following [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html) documentation on the Bash operator.
One can add environment variables to the bash operator so they can be used in the commands.

Is there a way to also add values from the airflow config that are stored as environment variables?

Or can we just transfer all environment variables here without having to list them all?

Comment: I don't know the airflow framework, but intuitively speaking, I would expect that by default the whole environment is passed to the bash child process. Did you check this (by using `bash_command='printenv'`?)

Comment: @Shark32 could you describe the main problem? yes - you can transfer all environment variables. yes - you can transfer the only one specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add whatever you want:

```py
import os

# one env
bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="bash_task",
    bash_command="echo $var1_name && echo $var2_name",
    env={
        "var1_name": "{{ <any jinja var> }}",
        "var2_name": "static value",
    },
)

# all env from airflow host
bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="bash_task",
    bash_command="echo $<any env var>",
    env=os.environ,
)

# all env from airflow host + extra env
bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="bash_task",
    bash_command="echo $<any env var>",
    env={**os.environ, "var1_name": "{{ <any jinja var> }}",
        "var2_name": "static value",},
)
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a good way to combine those two options? To use both all environment variables and define your own for this DAG?

Comment: I just updated my answer by adding an example